# RegEx Search Words and Avoid from some issues

Tags: python, regex

I want to find 'chapter' and 'part' words in a sentence

```
s1='part1'
s2='part 1'
s3='part: 1'
s4='part hello world'
s5='part: hello world'
s6='hello world part'

re.search('(?:chapter[\s,:,0-9]+|part[\s,:,0-9]+)',s6)
```

I tried `\bpart\b` it doesn't work for my problem.

But I should avoid 'part(y)', 'part(icular)', 'part(icipant)' and etc at the same time.

How can i write this with using regex?

Comment: Did you try: `\bpart\s*\d*\b`

Comment: You should try word boundary  ```\b(part|chapter)\b```

Comment: I think you need `re.search(r'\b(?:part|chapter)(?![A-Za-z])', s6)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9sEF2/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.search(r'\b(?:part|chapter)(?![A-Za-z])', s6)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9sEF2/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:part|chapter)` - a non-capturing group matching either `part` or `chapter` char sequences
- `(?![A-Za-z])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is an ASCII letter (replace `[A-Za-z]` with `[^\W\d_]` if you need to support any Unicode letters).

Answer (score 0):

make space `\s` and `:` optional using `([\s:]+)?`

```
text = '''part1
part 1
part: 1
part hello world
part: hello world
hello world part
party start
chapter1
chapter 1
chapter: 1'''

matches = re.findall(r"((?:chapter|part)(?:[\s:]+)?\d+)", text)

for m in matches:
    print(m)
```

Comment: sorry I'm reading too fast, I will modify

Comment: I think it does not match all `chapter` and part `words` and for some it matches more than only those words. https://regex101.com/r/iM8sgD/1